# Does this getter-setter Closure have a good reason to declare it's privates in it's inner object this way?

Tags: javascript, closures, encapsulation

I was following this:

[Javascript constructor patterns](http://www.samselikoff.com/blog/some-Javascript-constructor-patterns/) - scroll to "Closures with getter-setters (D3.js, jQuery))"

and I was confused by the way `my` is declared:

```
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
  var _firstName = firstName,                  // private 
      _lastName = lastName;                    // private 

  var my = {
    firstName: _firstName,                     // <- why?
    lastName: _lastName                        // <- why?
  };                                           // var my = {};?

  my.fullName = function() {                   
    return _firstName + ' ' + _lastName;       // a toString() wannabe
  };

  // Getter/setters
  my.firstName = function(value) {             
    if (!arguments.length) return _firstName;  // getter
    _firstName = value;                        // setter   

    return my; // enable "method chaining" ...
  };

  my.lastName = function(value) {              
    if (!arguments.length) return _lastName;   // getter
    _lastName = value;                         // setter  

    return my; // ... so mark.firstName('Samuel').lastName('Clemens'); works
  };

  return my; // expose inner object but not the private instance variables
}
```

The side comments in the section above were added to expose my thinking.

```
//Use it like this:

var mark = Person('Mark', 'Twain'); // note: no `new` keyword!

mark.firstName('Samuel');
mark.lastName('Clemens');

mark.fullName(); // Samuel Clemens
```

`var my = {};` seems to work when this is tested in chrome's console.  This code is meant to support encapsulation. Testing after this change hasn't revealed any new way into the privates or broken functionality.  But I worry there some magic I'm missing that required this.

Please check my thinking.  Isn't the _firstName in my.firstName just getting stepped on when it's redefined as a getter/setter function?  Am I exposing or breaking something by switching to `var my = {};`?

The **How does this work?** section says:

> "Typically, when a function finishes executing, the variables declared
>   within that function fall out of scope and get destroyed. But there's
>   an exception: if any code outside the function holds a reference to
>   these variables after the function finishes executing, they won't be
>   cleaned up. Instead, a closure will be formed, and those variables
>   will remain in memory."
>
> "In the example above, since the Person constructor function returns
>   the inner object my, and since my refers to the local variables
>   _firstName and _lastName (both in the getter/setters and in the fullName method), the variables are not destroyed. When the
>   getter/setters are invoked, they are operating on those same local
>   variables."

Comment: Pretty much, yes. The initialisation of `my` is pretty superfluous.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit ironic that most people i've seen "teaching" closures on blogs don't actually understand closures themselves. You are right, but there are a lot more redundant things in that code than just that one object.

```
function Person(firstName, lastName) { // [arguments] also "private"

  this.fullName = function() {                   
    return firstName + ' ' + lastName;       
  };

  this.firstName = function(value) {         // difficult to inspect
    if (!arguments.length) return firstName; // soon: How's this working?
    firstName = value;                       // yes those are still there
                                             // ...still there...
    return this;                             // ......always there....
  };                                         // ........forever........
                                             // ...haunting your memories
  this.lastName = function(value) {          // .......never forget...
    if (!arguments.length) return lastName;  // ....closure remembers...
    lastName = value;                        // ...dream within a dream..
                                             // ....within a closure....
    return this;                             // ...no one returns......
  };                                         // ...daddy..............
}                                            // where do dead memories go?
```

How does it work? Well scope is still there. so are firstName and lastName. You don't need to return an inner object either, there is absolutely no reason not to just construct an instance of Person.

But that pattern is also only useful if you plan to make something really fancy with it. For storing strings or integers or anything along that line it's ridiculously inefficient. No one stores tiny amounts of data in 3 functions plus a closure plus the data **per instance of the object** - 1000 instances of that Object are 1000 closures and 3000 functions **plus** the actual data ( in this unfair example it's of course only 2 strings which makes it even more ridiculous ).

So unless you make it worth it, just use a plain old boring prototype. I know it's boring but if you actually run both side by side this boring version that takes not only estimated 99% less memory ( you have 1 single object holding only the data you need per instance, the rest is shared ) it's also a lot easier to use because everything behaves exactly as you'd expect all the time.

```
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

Person.prototype = {
    get fullName () {
        return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    }
}
```

edit: But it's of course really good to experiment and try out new things, and better to try something and see for yourself how and why it is good or bad instead of blindly listening to advices like mine. I hope I wasn't overly or unfairly critical towards the author of the blog.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my doubts.  But, well, as the author and I both mentioned, the point of this code is encapsulation.  Now I'm not a big fan of the getter/setter pattern either.  I prefer "tell don't ask" and immutability but the getter/setter pattern is often used to demonstrate encapsulation, as is done here.    Your proposed alternative offers no encapsulation, thus no way to enforce validation or enforce immutability.  Are you sure you can't find something better?  Nice poem by the way.

Comment: This is a great explanation. I don't know if it solves the problem, but I definitely got a lot of value out of it.